# Cannot use array methods on array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects, react-hooks

I cannot use array methods on an array of objects. The shellsArray logs out `(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]` in the console, but I am unable to use array methods on it. The proto of the console says array(0)

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react'

const RecipeForm = (props) => {
    const [baseLayer, setBaseLayer] = useState('');
    const [condiment, setCondiment] = useState('');
    const [mixing, setMixing] = useState('');
    const [seasoning, setSeasoning] = useState('');
    const [shell, setShell] = useState('');
**let tacos = props.tacos;
    let shellsArray = tacos.shells;** // Shows an array that I cannot use array methods on
    console.log(shellsArray);

    const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        props.saveCombination(baseLayer, condiment, mixing, seasoning, shell);
        setBaseLayer('');
        setCondiment('');
        setMixing('');
        setSeasoning('');
        setShell('');
    }
    return (
        <form onSubmit={submitHandler} >
            <select className="base-layer" name="baseLayer" value={baseLayer} onChange={(e) => setBaseLayer(e.target.value)} required >
            <option>SELECT BASE LAYER</option>
            <option>Mexican</option>
            <option>Asian</option>
            </select>
            <select className="condiment" name="condiment" value={condiment} onChange={(e) => setCondiment(e.target.value)} required >
            <option>SELECT CONDIMENT</option>
            <option>Tomato</option>
            <option>Lettuce</option>
            </select>
            <select className="mixing" name="mixing" value={mixing} onChange={(e) => setMixing(e.target.value)} required >
            <option>SELECT MIXING</option>
            <option>Tomato</option>
            <option>Lettuce</option>
            </select>
            <select className="seasoning" name="seasoning" value={seasoning} onChange={(e) => setSeasoning(e.target.value)} required >
            <option>SELECT SEASONING</option>
            <option>Tomato</option>
            <option>Lettuce</option>
            </select>
            <select className="shell" name="shell" value={shell} onChange={(e) => setShell(e.target.value)} required >
            <option>SELECT SHELL</option>
            <option>Tomato</option>
            <option>Lettuce</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" className="submit" />
        </form>
    );
}

export default RecipeForm;
```

Comment: what methods are not working? and what is the error

Comment: You completely omit where your `props` are set. I also don't see any code using `shellsArray` other than the `console.log`.

Comment: "*The proto of the console says array(0)*" this means that the prototype is the `Array` constructor function, so you should be able to call array methods. What happens if you do?

Comment: I am trying to use foreach(), but when I use this React logs TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: How are you calling that? Can you show the code?

Comment: What's the complete log output `Object.getProtoypeOf(shellsArray)`?

Comment: When I use Object.getProtoypeOf(shellsArray), React logs this: TypeError: Object.getProtoypeOf is not a function
RecipeForm
C:/Web Development/Projects/Taco App/src/components/RecipeForm.js:11
   8 |    const [shell, setShell] = useState('');
   9 |    let tacos = props.tacos;
  10 |    let shellsArray = tacos.shells;
> 11 |    Object.getProtoypeOf(shellsArray);
     | ^  12 | 
  13 |    const submitHandler = (e) => {
  14 |        e.preventDefault();

Comment: Sorry, `getPrototypeOf`.

Comment: Both Object.getPrototypeOf(shellsArray) and getPropertyOf do not work

Comment: Please give us the code set `props`, that is to say the jsx creates a `RecipeForm` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your shells array is a prop, it looks like you're trying to use it before the prop is defined. This is a common situation, and the usual approach it to guard against the error by first testing if your array is defined or not. The easiest method is to use a shortcut conditional:

```
Array.isArray(shells) && shells.map(shell=>{}) //or whatever
```

Comment: This was the solution to my problem, thank you very much for resolving it